# how can I change joomla 3 template background color

Tags: joomla3.3

how can I change joomla3.x  template background color .I am trying it from css  but I can't get it. can any body tell me how can I change the color of joomla3.3 template background color?

Answer (score 1):

you can use Firebug or Inspect Element for online edit css and get which file you should editing.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your root folder and

```
administrator/templates/isis/css
```

You will find template.css (in my case it is isis template)

```
body {
margin: 0;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 18px;
color: #333;
background-color: #fff; //Change this to your desired color.
}
```